# Will using a dimmer switch damage a transformer?

Tags: lighting

I've been looking at lighting for a house I've just moved into, and see lots of low voltage lighting which is marked as not working with dimmer switches.

I can live without the dimming but will setting the dimmer to 50% say, 
a) actually damage the transformer or
b) just make the lights go off or flicker or something..

I would worry if accidentally dimming the light caused permanent damage.

Comment: Transformers expect sinusoidal power, not the chopped waveform that most triac type dimmers provide. Resistive loads and devices engineered to handle this "abuse" should be the only things driven by a triac dimmer.

Answer (score 1):

If they say they are not for use with a dimmer they mean it. Regardless if you set it at 50% and leave it or whatever. Yes, you will damage the transformers or electronics of the systems if you use them on an incompatible dimmer.

Don't forget, many low-voltage lighting systems can be used with magnetic or electronic low-voltage dimmers. You need to check the manufacturer's specs to be sure.

Lutron, a leader in dimmer technology, has a good explanation here: http://www.lutron.com/en-US/Education-Training/Pages/LCE/DimmingBasics.aspx

Comment: +1. That's largely what has kept me from installing home automation -- I'd either have to upgrade the non-dimmable CFLs, or get switches which were guaranteed full-on/full-off (and then have to repurchase if/when I do replace the bulb). The former's probably less wasteful, especially now that LED bulbs are becoming cheap, but given that part of the point of the exercise would be to reduce waste...